# Two GUIDs with the same value

Tags: sql-server, database, guid

In SQL Server, what is the probability of creating tow GUIDs with the same value with this code?

```
DECLARE @EmployeeID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
SET @EmployeeID = NEWID();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically a GUID is a 128-bit number, with 6 informational bits and 122 random ones. So the probability is 1/(2<sup>122</sup>), where 2<sup>122</sup> = 5.31 * 10<sup>36</sup>.

Here is a citation from my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5566816/694852):

> According to this document ([RFC 4122](http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)) and comparing with GUIDs generated by C#, they are of random type.
>
> This type has the following pattern: `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-Vxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`, where
>
> - `x` is random number and
> - `V` is a number with bit layout as 10yy, where yy are two random bits.
>
> So, here we have 122 random bits out of 128.